# Django Checkboxes

Tags: django

I am trying to have a form in django that uses checkboxes. I can hard code them in the HTML but I wanted to do it the Django way.

Forms.py

```
checkbox = forms.BooleanField(widget= forms.CheckboxInput,
                                    label='Mycheckbox',)
```

HMTL:

```
{% for field in form %}
       <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field }}{{ field.label }}</label>

{% endfor %}
```

Right now the form only will display the checkbox but not the label that I designated. I can use {{field.name}} but that will give me the name of the variable in the forms but not the label that I want it to display.